# Are there positive integers $x$, $y$ and prime numbers $p$ so that $\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}=\sqrt[3]{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a solution for this, but I'm not really sure about that:

> We have: $\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}=\sqrt[3]{p}$, multiplying both sides by $\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{xy}+\sqrt[3]{y^2}$ we get $x+y=\sqrt[3]{p}(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{xy}+\sqrt[3]{y^2})$ so $\sqrt[3]{px^2}-\sqrt[3]{pxy}+\sqrt[3]{py^2}$ is an integer.
>
> Suppose $\sqrt[3]{px^2}$, $\sqrt[3]{pxy}$, and $\sqrt[3]{py^2}$ are all integers, we can easily see that $p|x$ and $p|y$.
>
> Let $x^2=p^2a^3$, $y^2=p^2b^3$  where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. Then we can see that $a$ and $b$ also have to be perfect squares since $x=p\sqrt{a^3}$ and $y=p\sqrt{b^3}$ are integers. Since $\gcd(2,3)=1$, we can let $x^2=p^2a'^6$, $y^2=p^2b'^6$, or $x=pa'^3$, $y=pb'^3$ where $a'$ and $b'$ are integers. Subbing that to the original equation we get $\sqrt[3]{pa'^3}+\sqrt[3]{pb'^3}=\sqrt[3]{p}$, so $\sqrt[3]{p}(a'+b')=\sqrt[3]{p}$. But $a'+b'>1$, so $\sqrt[3]{p}(a'+b')>\sqrt[3]{p}$, hence a contradiction.

I can see I made a lot of assumptions here, like "Let $x^2=p^2a^3$, $y^2=p^2b^3$", or assuming all $\sqrt[3]{px^2}$, $\sqrt[3]{pxy}$, and $\sqrt[3]{py^2}$ are integers. Are there any problems with my work or is it good to go? And moreover, do you have a better solution than this? I appreciate your time and effort for this and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: $x+y=(\sqrt[3] x+\sqrt[3]y)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{xy}+\sqrt[3]{y^2})$, not $(\sqrt[3] x+\sqrt[3]y)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{xy}+\sqrt[3]{y^2})$. (I don't know whether this invalidates your proposed proof.)

Comment: Oh okay, my bad, let me edit that. And that shouldn't really matter in this proof, since I later assumed $\sqrt[3]{px^2}$, $\sqrt[3]{pxy}$, $\sqrt[3]{py^2}$ are integers.

Comment: I think that the only solutions to $\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}=\sqrt[3]{z}$ with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ are the "obvious" ones given by $(x,y,z)=(ka^3,kb^3,k(a+b)^3)$ where $a,b,k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I also tried to prove it that way, but I couldn't figure out how to show that these are the only solutions to that equation.

Comment: Yeah, your conclusion that $\sqrt[3]{px^2},$ etc are integers is not warranted. If you say that $u-v+w$ being an integer, then $u,v,w$ are all integers is certainly wrong.

Comment: In particular, there are solutions for integers $x,y.$ There are no positive solutions $x,y.$ For non-zero examples, $x=8p, y=-p.$

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of that, but the problem is that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, not integers where they are negative.

Comment: See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9290561S) for a simple proof of Geoffrey's statement above. So you would need to have $a+b=\pm 1$, so $a$ and $b$ (therefore $x$ and $y$) can't be both positive. So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang You're right, that are the only solution. Look in my solution and complete the details on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall the algebraic identity:

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc = \frac12(a+b+c)((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2)$$

Whenever $a+b+c = 0$, we have $a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3abc$.

Substitute $a,b,c$ by $\sqrt[3]{p}, -\sqrt[3]{x}, -\sqrt[3]{y}$ and let $K = p - x - y$, we find

$$K = p - x - y = 3\sqrt[3]{pxy} > 0$$
Since $x,y > 0$, $K$ is a positive integer smaller than $p$.

Taking cube on the equality on the left and using the condition $p$ is a prime, we have

$$K^3 = 27pxy \implies p | K^3 \implies p | K$$

This contradicts with above fact that $K$ is a positive integer smaller than $p$.

As a result, equation $\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{y} = \sqrt[3]{p}$ has not positive integer solutions for any prime $p$.

Comment: Man, this proof is so intuitive!

Answer (score 3):

Without using a specific formula, you can also construct a solution as follows:

$$\begin{align}&\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}=\sqrt[3]{p},\thinspace x,y\in\mathbb Z^{+}; p\in\mathbb P\\
\implies &x+y+3\sqrt [3]{xy}\left(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}\right)=p\\
\implies &x+y+3\sqrt[3]{pxy}=p\\
\implies &27 pxy=(p-x-y)^3 \\
\implies &p\mid (p-x-y)^3\\
\implies &p\mid p-x-y \\
\implies &p≤p-x-y ,\thinspace p>x+y≥2 \\
\implies &x+y≤0,~\text{A contradiction.}\end{align}$$

Comment: It should be $p \le p-x-y$, not $p<p-x-y$, which means that $x+y \le 1$, which is still a contradiction since $x$, $y$ are positive integers.

Comment: @Hai But $x+y≤0$ not $x+y≤1$.

Comment: @Aqua Hello. Because, $\text{LHS}=27pxy>0$. You can ask why do I need this restriction, because  e.g $4|-8$ but $4>-8$. I noted this restriction in the required step, do you wish I  have noted it earlier?  I just wanted to note it as soon as it went into use.

Comment: It is ok .............

Comment: @Aqua $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{y} = \sqrt[3]{p}$. Then
\begin{gather*}
(\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{y})^3 = x+y+3\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{y}(\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{y}) = p \\
\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{y}\sqrt[3]{p} =\sqrt[3]{xyp} = \frac{p-x-y}{3} \in \mathbb{Q}
\end{gather*}
It can be shown that this implies that $\sqrt[3]{xyp} \in \mathbb{Z}$

The, multiplying the original equation by $\sqrt[3]{xp}$ and squaring we have
\begin{gather*}
\sqrt[3]{xp^2} = \sqrt[3]{xyp} +\sqrt[3]{x^2p} = z +\sqrt[3]{x^2p} \\
(\sqrt[3]{xp^2})^2 = p\sqrt[3]{x^2p} =z(\sqrt[3]{xp^2}) +xp
\end{gather*}

This is equivalent to a system of 2 equations. Let $a=\sqrt[3]{xp^2}, b=\sqrt[3]{x^2p}$
\begin{align*}
a - b &= z \\
za - pb &= -xp 
\end{align*}

There are 2 cases. If the system is indeterminate, then $z=p=-x$, contradiction. If not, then $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then also $\sqrt[3]{y^2p} = \frac{(\sqrt[3]{xyp})^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^2p}} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt[3]{yp^2} = \frac{(\sqrt[3]{xyp})(\sqrt[3]{xp^2})}{\sqrt[3]{x^2p}} \in \mathbb{Q}$. A similiar reasoning also leads to $\sqrt[3]{xy^2}, \sqrt[3]{x^2y} \in \mathbb{Q}$

That means that
$\sqrt[3]{xyp}, \sqrt[3]{x^2p}, \sqrt[3]{y^2p}, \sqrt[3]{xp^2}, \sqrt[3]{yp^2}, \sqrt[3]{xy^2}, \sqrt[3]{x^2y} \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is on your “Suppose that…” line. You need to prove that, and it can be a bit of work. The rest of the proof is fine.

A similar more direct argument just cubes both sides to get:

$$x+3\sqrt[3]{x^2y}+ 3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}+y=p$$

Letting $u= 3\sqrt[3]{x^2y},v= 3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}$ then $u+v=p-x-y$ and $uv=9xy.$

This means $u$ is a root of the two integer polynomials:

$$f(w)=w^3-27x^2y\\g(w)=w^2-(p-x-y)w+9xy$$

If $u$ is not an integer, then $g$ must be the minimal polynomial for $u,$ so $g$ must divide $f.$ The only possible factorization is:

$$f(w)=(w-3x)g(w).$$

Then $$0=f(3x)=27x^3-27x^2y=27x^2(x-y),$$ and we get $x=0$ or $x=y.$ But $x>0$ and, if $x=y,$ we’d have $$ \sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y=\sqrt[3]{8x}=\sqrt[3]p$$ or $p=8x,$ contradicting that $p$ is prime.

So $u$ must be an integer, and the same for $v.$

So $x^2y$ and $xy^2$ must be perfect cubes. Then $$\frac xy=\frac{x^2y}{xy^2}=\left(\frac ab\right)^3$$ for positive integers $a,b.$ This means $a^3x=b^3y.$

Then $$\begin{align} a\sqrt[3]p&=a(\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]{y})\\
&=(a+b)\sqrt[3]y\end{align}$$

Cubing both sides:

$$a^3p=(a+b)^3y.\tag1$$

So $p$ must divide $y.$ But then $y\geq p.$

Similarly $x\geq p.$

But then $$\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y>\sqrt[3]p,$$ a contradiction.

---

The general question of integer roots to:

$$\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y=\sqrt[3]{z}$$ works the same, but you have to allow $x=0,y=z$ and $x=y,$ and $z=8x.$

When you get to (1), you have to write $z=z_0z_1^3,$ where $z_0$ has non nontrivial cube divisors.  Then for (1) you get:

$$(az_1)^3z_0=(a+b)^3y.$$ This means $y=z_0y_1^3$ and then, similarly, $x=z_0x_1^3,$ and you get $x_1+y_1=z_1,$ so all solutions can be written:

$$(x,y,z)=\left(z_0x_1^3,z_0y_1^3,z_0(x_1+y_1)^3\right)$$

For all positive cube-free $z_0$ and integers $x_1,y_1.$